# Choosing between Improve Edit and Reject and Edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

Just starting to use the review queue and I'm wondering what the functional difference is between the two and how people decide on which one to use?

A good amount of the edits I see are usually just a line or two, but it looks like the post could still use substantial editing.  Should I be "improving" these somewhat minor (but good) edits, or should I be rejecting them and editing the whole post myself.

Comment: You reject anything that isn't a good edit. Edits should at least try to fix everything that is obvious that can be fixed. If you feel that has been done, choose improve. If the editor only removed a *Thanks* or *hello* while leaving obvious other stuff untouched, reject and/or reject and edit.